# Netbeans does not open html files

Tags: netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1 for PHP (on Lubuntu) and i have an issue when trying to open HTML files.

If i double click on an HTML file, in the files panel, it won't open. I have to right click and select open instead.

This is really annoying, it never used to happened.

Comment: I have same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: It appears to me that if the cursor moves even a single pixel, it won't open the file.  I'm not sure if that's the problem you're having, but it's definitely a huge issue for me, as I use a Wacom pen, and it's very hard to keep it perfectly still while pressing the double-click button.  It's so frustrating...  anyone come up with a solution??